# Returning function values issue

Tags: php

I have an issue with one of my functions returning data, here is my code:

```
function getLinks($host, $hash, $count) {
    require_once('api-sape.php');
    $sape        = new SapeApi();
    $userId      = $sape->login(SAPE_USER, SAPE_PASS);  
    // query the database for the proper strings to return
    $sql1 = DB::getInstance()->select("SELECT * FROM `purchased` WHERE `purchased_site_hash`='".$hash."' LIMIT ".$count."");
    $results = "";
    foreach ($sql1 as $row) {
              $sq2 = DB::getInstance()->selectValues("SELECT * FROM `projects` WHERE `project_sape_id`='".$row['purchased_project_id']."'");
              //echo "URL: " . $sq2['project_url'];
              //echo "<br />";
              //echo "Text: " . $row['purchased_text'];
              $url    = $sq2['project_url'];
              $txt    = $row['purchased_text'];
              // do some string manipulation
              $arr    = array("#a#" => '<a href="'.$url.'">', "#/a#" => "</a>");
              $result = strtr($txt, $arr);
              //echo $result;
              $results = $result;
              echo $result;
    }
    print_r($results);
    return [$results];
     return [
        'some text <a href="link">text</a> some text',
        'some text <a href="link">text</a> some text'
    ]; 
}
```

I'm returning values in this format:

```
 return [
    'some text <a href="link">text</a> some text',
    'some text <a href="link">text</a> some text'
];
```

Depending on how many strings there is, the "return" should return the number of strings from above, there is 2 strings in this case but it is only returning 1, if i echo out: **echo $result;** in the foreach it's fine, it's getting the values to the return [] i'm having problems with, any help would be appreciated!

Comment: $results = $result; is meaningless. Define $results as array and use $results[] = $result;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be careful! You're returning an array containing the `$results` array, you should return `$results`.

`[$val]` is a shortcut to the `array($val)` function. So in your case, you're returning an array containing an array. So if you really want to return an array, you'll have to access to the first value (`[0]`) of the returned array.

Source: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php